# Google Compute Engine Startup Script Cant Execute

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am having trouble getting the following startup-script to execute properly when launching a Compute Engine Instance (GCE).

```
#! /bin/bash
setup vncserver
vnc4server -geometry 1440x900 :1
export DISPLAY=:1
echo "completed"
```

The script is read by GCE but does not execute the commands and the log shows blank lines with a message in-between which is the key to the problem but I cant seem to solve it.

Log shows the following:

```
Feb  3 09:15:33 simpleapache3 startupscript: Running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
Feb  3 09:15:34 simpleapache3 startupscript:
Feb  3 09:15:34 simpleapache3 startupscript: You will require a password to access your desktops.
Feb  3 09:15:34 simpleapache3 startupscript:
```

How do I get around the "You will require a password..." section?

Tried:

I tried adding in a password inside the script like this but no luck...

```
#! /bin/bash
#setup vncserver
vnc4server -geometry 1440x900 :1
myPassword123
export DISPLAY=:1
echo "completed"
```

Notes:

I have got VNC4SERVER already installed on the persistent disk I am adding.
If I ssh into the instance and run the commands manually they work perfectly and I am not asked for a password.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because the startup scripts run as `root` rather than your user.

This script works for me:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "I am: " `whoami`
sudo -u briandorsey DISPLAY=:1 vnc4server -geometry 1440x900 :1
echo "completed"
```

Replace `briandorsey` with your username.

Also, don't forget to create a firewall rule to allow vnc traffic. This can be done via the [Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) or with `gcutil`:

```
gcutil addfirewall vnc2 --allowed=tcp:5901
```

This will allow traffic on port 5901 to all virtual machines in your project. See the [firewall docs](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls) for information on how to limit access further.

Comment: Hi @briandorsey: I get the following error message when I run the suggested script you provided: steven@exportdisplay:~$ sudo -u steven DISPLAY=:1 vnc4server -geometry 1440x900 :1 Sorry, user steven is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/vnc4server -geometry 1440x900 :1' as steven on exportdisplay.c.{projectname}.internal..... Do I need to activate some user permissions?

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like you may be running? this script interactively as the user 'steven'? The script is meant to be  run as a startup-script.

Comment: When I ran it as a startup script nothing happened. The logs show up blank. I then tried to run it interactively to see if it would work then and Yes, I got the error message saying I dont have permission. I am going to try some other things and see how far I get. Maybe the issue is the startup script is hosted on Google Cloud Storage. Will use a local file instead and report back.